# Redim Preserve in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I was shocked to find out today that C# does not support dynamic sized arrays. How then does a [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) developer used to using [ReDim Preserve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) deal with this in C#?

At the beginning of the function I am not sure of the upper bound of the array. This depends on the rows returned from the database.

Comment: I think the other side would say "I am shocked to find out that VB supports dynamically sized arrays."

Comment: yeah sixlettervariables, it seems dynamic sized arrays were all too easy to use, but at a serious performance cost.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use ArrayLists or Generics instead

Comment: More precisely, use List<T>. There are plenty of generic classes or functions in .NET that aren't resizeable arrays. ;)

Comment: I would stay away from ArrayLists. Besides being harder to use, Microsoft has said they won't be available on new platforms like Silverlight.

Comment: Silverlight is gone now @JonathanAllen. going to disappear.

Comment: The exact equivalent of ReDim Preserve is [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/327958/2040663) by [@JonSkeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 83):

VB.NET doesn't have the idea of dynamically sized arrays, either - the CLR doesn't support it.

The equivalent of "Redim Preserve" is [`Array.Resize<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) - but you *must* be aware that if there are other references to the original array, they won't be changed at all. For example:

```
using System;

class Foo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] x = new string[10];
        string[] y = x;

        Array.Resize(ref x, 20);
        Console.WriteLine(x.Length); // Prints out 20
        Console.WriteLine(y.Length); // Still prints out 10
    }
}
```

Proof that this is the equivalent of Redim Preserve:

```
Imports System

Class Foo
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim x(9) as String
        Dim y as String() = x

        Redim Preserve x(19)
        Console.WriteLine(x.Length)
        Console.WriteLine(y.Length)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The two programs are equivalent.

If you truly want a dynamically sized collection, you should use `List<T>` (or something similar). There are various issues with using arrays directly - see [Eric Lippert's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx) for details. That's not to say you should always avoid them, by any means - but you need to know what you're dealing with.

Comment: There is one difference between the techniques.  Array.Resize works only on zero-based single dimensional arrays.  Redim works on multi-dimensional arrays.  No sure about the zero-based portion

Comment: also worth noting.. and I don't know if it's the case with redim. But worth noting also that with C#, Array.Resize will make the variable point to a new array (as can be seen with Object.ReferenceEquals(..). So y and x now point to two different arrays.. y is no longer an alias for x.. And changing x[0] will no longer change y[0].  and you now have two arrays rather than one.

Comment: @barlop: Yes, that's precisely what the example demonstrates... and why I wrote: "The equivalent of "Redim Preserve" is Array.Resize<T> - but you must be aware that if there are other references to the original array, they won't be changed at all."

Comment: I have always thought (assumed) that if the new size was smaller it would reuse the same memory and just "trim" the excess. Reference Source clearly shows that you will get a new array every time.

Comment: @ChadSchouggins: Wouldn't it be good if...? Super-efficient shrinking array.

Comment: @JaredPar: This can be combatted in some ways by multiplying out your multidimensional array into a single dimension, then increasing your array size by orders of magnitude. Not a true solution, I know, but a possibility.

Answer (score 12):

Use a List<T>. It will dynamically size as needed.

Comment: @user7116 ***never*** ? why and reasons ?

Answer (score 6):

You really shouldn't be using ReDim, it can be very expensive. I prefer List(Of T), but there are many options in this area.

That said, you had a question and here is your answer.

```
x = (int[]) Utils.CopyArray((Array) x, new int[10]);
```

Comment: How do you think that List<T> copes when it needs to resize its internal buffer? It does exactly the same as ReDim Preserve, basically... Why do you think ReDim is expensive, but not List<T>? (List<T> is certainly more convenient in many ways, but they basically need to do the same thing...)

Comment: Jon, Isn't ReDim Preserve adding what we need at the time we ask and List<T> doubling the size as .net thinks it's needed? I would assume this is monitored and doubled when the framework thinks it's optimum to do so and thus less expensive? Thanks!

Comment: We have to put things in context to see the differences between ReDim Preserve (actually Array.Copy) and List<T>.
If you’re doing your resizing inside a loop, after a number of iterations, List<T> ends up allocating less memory than ReDim Preserve. 
That happens because while a new array is created for each loop iteration with Redim Preserve, with List<T> new arrays only are created when the current one does not have space for a new element.

Comment: the only one that gave an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't help but notice that *none* of the above answers approach the concept of multidimensional arrays. That being said, here's an example. The array in question is predefined as `x`.

```
int[,] temp = new int[newRows, newCols];
int minRows = Math.Min(newRows, x.GetUpperBound(0) + 1);
int minCols = Math.Min(newCols, x.GetUpperBound(1) + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < minRows ; ++i)
     for (int j = 0; j < minCols; ++j)
         temp[i, j] = x[i, j];
x = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's one way to use generics in order to redim/extend a unidimensional array (add one more "row") :

```
static T[] Redim<T>(T[] arr, bool preserved)
{
    int arrLength = arr.Length;
    T[] arrRedimed = new T[arrLength + 1];
    if (preserved)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
        {
            arrRedimed[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return arrRedimed;
}
```

And one to add n rows (though this doesn't prevent user from undersizing the array, which will throw an error in the for loop)  :

```
static T[] Redim<T>(T[] arr, bool preserved, int nbRows)
{
    T[] arrRedimed = new T[nbRows];
    if (preserved)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arrRedimed[i] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return arrRedimed;
}
```

I'm sure you get the idea.

For a multidimensional array (two dimensions), here's one possibility:

```
static T[,] Redim<T>(T[,] arr, bool preserved)
{
    int Ubound0 = arr.GetUpperBound(0);
    int Ubound1 = arr.GetUpperBound(1);
    T[,] arrRedimed = new T[Ubound0 + 1, Ubound1];
    if (preserved)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Ubound1; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Ubound0; i++)
            {
                arrRedimed[i, j] = arr[i, j];
            }
        }
    }
    return arrRedimed;
}
```

In your program, use this with or even without the type specified, the compiler will recognize it :

```
int[] myArr = new int[10];
myArr = Redim<int>(myArr, true);
```

or

```
int[] myArr = new int[10];
myArr = Redim(myArr, true);
```

Not sure if all this is really relevant though. =D
Please feel free to correct me or improve my code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's a long time ago it might help someone looking for a simple solution - I found something great in another forum:

```
//from Applied Microsoft.NET framework Programming - Jeffrey Richter
public static Array RedimPreserve(Array origArray, Int32 desiredSize)
        {
            System.Type t = origArray.GetType().GetElementType();
            Array newArray = Array.CreateInstance(t, desiredSize);
            Array.Copy(origArray, 0, newArray, 0, Math.Min(origArray.Length, desiredSize));
            return newArray;
        }
```

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6759816b-d525-4752-a3c8-9eb5f4a5b194/redim-in-c?forum=csharplanguage