# Redim Statement in VB and C#

Tags: c#, vb6

What will be the C# equivalent of the following  `ReDim a(0 To i, 0 To 1)` ?

I am trying to implement using it by Array.resize ... but it's not working.

Comment: "not working" is never an acceptable problem description. Provide the actual code that you tried. =)

Comment: If you are trying to implement it, then you'll have some code. Do you think it would help us if we could see that code?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327916/redim-preserve-in-c

Answer (score 5):

Since you aren't using `Preserve`, this is just:

```
a = new SomeType[i,1];
```

More generally `Array.Resize` (which is akin to `ReDim Preserve`) only works on *vectors* (1-dimensional 0-based arrays); there is not an overload for multi-dimensional arrays. You can, however, simply *create a new array* and then copy the data from the old array to the new array in a loop. However, frankly if you are routinely resizing arrays, then something might be wrong in your code - maybe consider some kind of nested list; or since your second direction is always 0-1, either two separate arrays/lists, or a single array/list of a type with two members.

Comment: +1 especially for suggesting replacing with "two separate arrays/lists, or a single array/list of a type with two members"