# Creating multidimensional array at runtime

Tags: c#

I did my research on the web but I couldn't find any advice how to dynamically create multidimensional (rank >1) array (it could be a jagged array).

In other words program will ask about number of dimensions (rank) first, then about number of elements per dimension (rank) and then it will create the array.

Is it possible?

Comment: refer to this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327916/redim-preserve-in-c)

Comment: @Nimesh: thanks for the link. At least it talks about re-sizing of the arrays.

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå: could you be more constructive?

Comment: and why I got negative marks on my questions?

Comment: Anything about dynamic re-ranking (re-dimensoning)?

Comment: why not use Lists instead?

Comment: @Zohar Peled can I have multidimensional lists? I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

multidimensional no, but no problem with jagged - here is a simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        List<List<List<int>>> myJaggedIntList = new List<List<List<int>>>();

        myJaggedIntList.Add(new List<List<int>>());
        myJaggedIntList[0].Add(new List<int>());
        myJaggedIntList[0][0].Add(3);

        Console.WriteLine(myJaggedIntList[0][0][0].ToString());
    }
}
```

each item in the first `List` is a `List`, each item in the second `List` is also a `List`, and each item in the third `List` is an `int`. what's the problem with that?

[Play with it yourself in this fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/T3vPEh)