# IndexOutOfRange Exception in code converted from VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have this VB code

```
 Public Function InitJobTicketConcaveItemsType() As JobTicketConcaveItemsType
        Dim OutData As JobTicketConcaveItemsType
        With OutData
            .NumJobItems = 1
            ReDim .JobItems(.NumJobItems - 1)
            .JobItems(0) = JobDataConcaveEnum.JDBDryData
        End With
        Return OutData
    End Function
```

The converted **C#** code

```
public static JobTicketConcaveItemsType InitJobTicketConcaveItemsType()
        {
            JobTicketConcaveItemsType OutData = default(JobTicketConcaveItemsType);
            var _with25 = OutData;

            _with25.NumJobItems = 1;
            // ERROR: Not supported in C#: ReDimStatement - replaced with the statement below
            Array.Resize(ref _with25.JobItems, _with25.NumJobItems - 1);

            _with25.JobItems[0] = FrontEndEnums.JobDataConcaveEnum.JDBDryData;
            return OutData;
        }
```

When I try to run the application , I get a the Error IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled. I have made sure to use **Array.Resize()** to reallocate the array

The code in VB doesn´t give errors. Any clues ?

JDBDryData has been defined as below

```
public enum JobDataConcaveEnum
        {
            JDBWetData = 0,
            JDBDryData,
            JDBWetCylinder,
            JDBAxis
        }
```

I get the error at the statement

```
_with25.JobItems[0]=FrontEndEnums.JobDataConcaveEnum.JDBDryData;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redim Preserve in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327916/redim-preserve-in-c)

Comment: No its not.. I have already used Array.Resize(). Even after doing this I am getting error

Comment: Isn't `_with25.NumJobItems - 1` zero ? This is not the start index, this is the length of the array.

Comment: thats what I am thinking. The size is 0

Comment: If the size is zero, you can't access element at index 0 (element 1)

Comment: the code in VB is not throwing errors. I dont know why? is Array.Resize() is an alternate to Redim ?

Comment: @Apoorv Have you checked my code in the comment :)

Comment: Do you want to delete the last element from your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [VB array declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx), you specify the last valid index:

```
'Declare a single-dimension array of 5 values
Dim numbers(4) As Integer
```

In [C# array declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx), you specify the length of the array.

That means that you should always add 1 when converting a VB array declaration to a C# one. So, simply, don't subtract that 1:

```
Array.Resize(ref _with25.JobItems, _with25.NumJobItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you resize the `_with25.JobItems` array to size `0` in following line of your code.

`Array.Resize(ref _with25.JobItems, _with25.NumJobItems - 1);`

then what happen is your array size become zero.
when it comes to line

`_with25.JobItems[0] = FrontEndEnums.JobDataConcaveEnum.JDBDryData;`

which you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception, you can see, you are trying to set a value to zero'th element of an array where there is no elements at all(array of zero size)

remove the `Array.Resize(ref _with25.JobItems, _with25.NumJobItems - 1);` 
Or edit the same line as follows
`Array.Resize(ref _with25.JobItems, _with25.NumJobItems);` and see.

Comment: NullReferenceException was unhandled. Object Reference not set to instance of the object

Comment: @Apoorv check `Array.Resize(ref _with25.JobItems, _with25.NumJobItems);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot resize array to size 0, as other answers mentioned already. 
Also, you need to know that Array size declared in VBscript is 1 more than C#. So make sure that you provide the proper size. Therefore, in your case you cannot blatantly convert `_with25.NumJobItems - 1` from VBScript to C# without adjusting the number.

Regarding Array size in VBScript and C#:

- VB script:

  Dim arr(5)

  ' Size is 6, and you can access them by arr(0), arr(1), ... arr(5)
- C#

  MyType[] arr = new MyType[5];

  // Size is 5, and you can access them by arr[0], arr[1], ... arr[4]

Answer (score 0):

You won´t need to use `Array.Resize`at all, simply copy the content from the existing array into a new one and store this into the original one using `Array.CopyTo`:

```
var tmp = with25.JobItems;

with25.JobItems = new MyType[_with25.NumJobItems]; 
tmp.CopyTo(with25.JobItems, 0);
```

Comment: No, [`With` blocks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) are just shorthand for avoiding having to specify the same variable (or variable + chain or property accessors) for multiple statements that interact with the same object. Nothing "transactional" here.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers are confusing 'ReDim' with 'ReDim Preserve'. For the conversion of a simple 'ReDim', no Array.Resize call is necessary or even recommended - the C# equivalent is just:

```
public JobTicketConcaveItemsType InitJobTicketConcaveItemsType()
{
    JobTicketConcaveItemsType OutData = new JobTicketConcaveItemsType();
    OutData.NumJobItems = 1;
    OutData.JobItems = new foo[OutData.NumJobItems];
    OutData.JobItems[0] = JobDataConcaveEnum.JDBDryData;
    return OutData;
}
```