# How do I delete items in a multidimensional array and will it change the array length?

Tags: c#

Say I have a 3d array:

```
int[,,] arr = new int[3, 2, 3];
```

How can I delete all items under one of the first dimension? And if that can be done, will that move up all the values under it? Or will the deleted items just take null values and be counted in the `arr.GetLength(0)` method?

Comment: What is the desired result, please?

Comment: You can't delete items from arrays (or add extra ones). Arrays, whether single-dimensional or multi-dimensional, have fixed sizes after creation.

Comment: Why not make a new array with just the items you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a C# version of the Visual Basic's `ReDim` method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/327958/9076546
Note that dynamic array sizes aren't the best for performance. `ReDim` was a mistake in my honest opinion...